# Where is "Enable gather of GPU Disassembly" in visual studio 2017?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, pixel-shader

I need to debug a pixel shader, but I get the following message instead of disassembly:

```
Enable GPU disassembly via View->Options->Graphics Diagnostics->Enable gather of GPU Disassembly.
The vsglog must be re-opened for this change to take effect.
```

I cannot see that option in settings though:

[image]

Is it still available? Could the error be wrong and something is causing the missing information?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40808/graphics-diagnostics-failed-to-build-shader-trace.html

Comment: Well, the post says it's fixed. But that response is from 2017 and I have Visual Studio that was last updated last week. So either the issue is back, or I have another problem.

Comment: @TomášZato Hi friend, what project do you creates? Can you provide some steps to reproduce this issue?If it's reproducible, I suggest you could post this issue by `Help menu=>Send a feedback=>Report a problem` to post it.

Comment: I have never, and still don't, see this option... wish i did though.